# TObjectList.Clear access violation

Tags: delphi

I'm running into a very weird problem with a large application. I make heavy use of TObjectList storing a custom object on them. On large lists im experiencing weird crashes with "Access violation at address.. read of address.. " "privileged instruction" and others, when I use the CLEAR method. I've tracked this to happen exactly when attempting to delete the last item in the list. I've checked this by logging the contained objects deletion from their destroy proc, and also trying to deleting them on my own (for a := olist.count-1 downto 0 do.. debugmsg('deleting '+inttostr(a)).. olist.delete(a) ), both ways I get the access violation right when deleting the LAST remaining item in the list.

This doesnt happen always, cause I use clear in other areas, and also a few different (smaller) lists, but at a very specific point in my app this happens.

I've no clue what might be wrong, there's nothing trying to access the list during the clear, and the cointained objects do not have access to their parent objectlist, there has to be something screwing up in the TObjectList.delete/clear methods when it comes to clearing the last item.

Any suggestions? Using Delphi XE.

Comment: Looks like a memory corruption that occurs elsewhere and you just see the echo.

Comment: TObjectList has an `OwnsObjects` property.  Is it True or False? What does your code that is using the TObjectList actually look like?

Comment: @Remy: from the bit about "also trying to deleting them on my own," it's pretty clear that `OwnsObjects` is set to `true`.

Comment: @Mason: Nothing is clear without seeing the actual code.  `OwnsObjects` could be False and hikari would be leaking objects.  TObjectList did not always have an `OwnsObjects` property.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That sounds to me like you're freeing objects that have already been freed.  To track this down, [download the full version of FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/files/FastMM%204.x%20Stable%20Releases/FastMM%204.97/FastMM497.zip/download), add `FullDebugMode` to the Conditional Defines line under Project Options->Delphi Compiler and the Map File option under Linking set to Detailed, and rebuild.  (Build, not Compile.)  Then copy the FullDebugMode DLL to the same folder as your EXE and run it.  It'll watch your memory as you allocate and free and when you try to free the same object for a second time, it'll catch that and give you some very detailed debug data as to where the problem is coming from.

Comment: +1 This is the most likely cause of the problem, and the best way to attempt a fix. There are other possible causes, but try this first.

Comment: oh wow that's nice, already seeing some problems "FastMM has detected an attempt to call a virtual mehtod on a freed object. An access violation will now be raised in order to abort the current operation."
Gonna take a bit to analyze all this, but this is a big help. Will report back soon. Thanks :)

Comment: @Hikari: Yep, that's the one.  Just make sure when you do a release build that you turn FullDebugMode *off.*

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the last object is valid and not already deleted? It could be in the list twice e.g. due to other bugs.